# How to set maximum popup width in Oracle ADF

Tags: jsf, popup, richfaces, oracle-adf

I work with Oracle ADF 11 and use RichPopup to display messages. By default, the popup width is aligned to the width of the message. Very long message makes popup too wide. Is there any way to bound the maximum popup width with some value, e.g. 300px?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width and height to a dialogue inside popup

```
 <af:popup id="supportDocPopup" contentDelivery="lazyUncached" >
     <af:dialog id="d2" **contentHeight="100" contentWidth="300"**>
        </af:dialog>
   </af:popup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a af:dialog and place the message there. Then customize the af:dialog width and height from the property panel and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use AFStretchWidth style class

```
<af:popup id="popup1">
     <af:panelWindow id="pw1" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" >

     </af:panelWindow>
</af:popup>
```